# Laravel Controller if conditions depends on inputs fileds

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a edit function for my user's where they can edit their own data, but i want it to depends on what the user will change and if the other field is not changed will be at is. you will see the code below and its not working if only one is changed but if i changed all of them the data will be changed.

> Myprofile // my users view

```
 <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="{{ route('updateprofilemany',  ['id' => auth()->user()->id]) }}" >  
            @csrf
            //username
            <input class="col-md-3 container justify-content-center form-control {{$errors->has('username') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->username }}" Value="{{ Request::old('username') }}"   />  
            //bio
           <textarea class="border-info form-control {{$errors->has('bio') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" type="text" name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->bio }}" Value="{{ Request::old('bio') }}"></textarea>  <br /> 

           <button id="btn-login" class="btn btn-md r btn-primary" type="submit" > <i class="fa fa-cog"> </i> Save Changes </button>

</form>
```

> StudentController.php // my users controller

```
public function   updateprofilemany(Request $request, $id)
{
   // Validation 
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'max:15|unique:Students',
        'bio' => 'max:50',   
  ]);

    if ($request->has('username'))
    {
        // if there is a new username value
        $username = $request->input('username');

    }  else {
        $username = Auth::user()->username;
    }

    if ($request->has('bio'))
    {
        // if there is a new username value
        $bio = $request->input('bio');

    }  else {
        $bio = Auth::user()->bio;
    }

    // Find the user and inject the new data if there is then go back to 
    myprofile
    $students = User::find($id);
    $students->username = $username;
    $students->bio = $bio;


    $students->save();


    //redirect
    return redirect()->route('myprofile');
}
```

it can read the data but if I add it inside the if else statements it requires the both fields.

I tried passing default data like this

> myprofile // users view

```
     <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="{{ route('updateprofilemany',  ['id' => auth()->user()->id, 'username' => auth()->user()->username, 'bio' => auth()->user()->bio]) }}" >  
            @csrf
            //username
            <input class="col-md-3 container justify-content-center form-control {{$errors->has('username') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->username }}" Value="{{ Request::old('username') }}"   />  
            //bio
           <textarea class="border-info form-control {{$errors->has('bio') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" type="text" name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->bio }}" Value="{{ Request::old('bio') }}"></textarea>  <br /> 

           <button id="btn-login" class="btn btn-md r btn-primary" type="submit" > <i class="fa fa-cog"> </i> Save Changes </button>

</form>
```

> Web.php // routes

```
//  calls user update profile many function
Route::post('/updateprofilemany/{id}', [
'uses' => 'StudentController@updateprofilemany',
'as' => 'updateprofilemany',
'name' => 'updateprofilemany'
]);
```

> Student Controller

```
  public function   updateprofilemany(Request $request, $id, $username ,$bio)
{
  //functions like above
 }
```

and add it the specific function like

```
 public function Functionname(Request $request, $id, $username, $bio)
```

can  you guys help me with this thank you!

Comment: can your provide proper studentcontrol function ? cause its hard to understand

Comment: use code like `$student = User::find($id);
    if ($request->has('username'))
    {
        $student->username = $request->input('username');

    }
    $student->save();`

Comment: Wouldn't `if ($request->has('username'))`  always be true?

Comment: i updated my codes so you guys can check

Comment: @kerbholz so putting and else statement wont work?

Comment: Grab the user you are trying to update, compare fields and see what changed and unset() untouched fields.

Comment: update `if ($request->has('username'))` to `f ($request->has('username')) && !empty($request->input('username'))` in the method provided in my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Value="{{ Request::old('username') }}"` in your username field, it may be empty because it doesn't have any value in the first time you open that page.
And in the controller when you use `if ($request->has('username'))` , it returns true because the username field is sent but with empty value.

You should check the username field for empty value and then continue ...

for example :

```
if ($request->filled('username')) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: if i input something in my username and leave the bio blank it will work, but if i do bio and leave username blank it wont work

Comment: Maybe your bio column is nullable But username not

Comment: i think i fixed it using your code, its wierd cuase if i get rid of the validation it will work. so what i did is put my validation inside the if true statement , wondering if this is safe?

Comment: Ok, yes anyway this is a kind of validation and it doesn't have problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the data when it is in the request you can just pass a default value to the input function. This will use the value if the key is not present in the request. If the key exists but it is an empty string then you can check with a ternary statement to see if there is a value.

This is probably the most simple way to write it:

```
public function updateprofilemany(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'max:15|unique:Students',
        'bio' => 'max:50'
    ]);

    // get the user
    $student = User::find($id);

    // just pass the default value as the old username if the key is not supplied
    // and if it is an empty string it will also use the old username
    $student->username = $request->input('username', $student->username) 
                         ?: $student->username;

    // also pass the default here as the old bio
    $student->bio = $request->input('bio', $student->bio)
                    ?: $student->bio;

    $student->save();

}
```

Comment: i tried but it just work if  i input on both of them, but if let say i just wanna change my username then its just refreshing no errors or something Thank you anyways :)

Comment: if i input something in my username and leave the bio blank it will work, but if i do bio and leave username blank it wont work

Comment: Can you explain what actually happens? Instead of saying it doesn't work